# Vue.js: addRoutes method with array from API call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, router, vue-router

I am going to use the addRoutes method for the first time. I didn't find any full tutorials of how developers can use this method so I decided to try and ask here.

In my app I have some sort of CMS so a user can create new pages with custom paths. In my router/index.js file where I import components and declare their routes I need to add these custom routes.

I have an API endpoint which can give me a JSON with arrays of these routes. How can I call this endpoint in my router/index.js file and add these new routes to my router?

Here is what I have in my router.index.js file (I added its structure rather than code itself):

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import http from '../http';
import config from '../config';
import Home from '../components/pages/Home';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
 mode: 'history',
 routes: [
  {
   path: '/home',
   name: 'home',
   component: Home,
  },
  ...
  ],
});

router.addRoutes([]);

export default router;
```

Comment: I don't recommend that you add these routes in the main file like this. Create a routes.js file and require it. If you use vue cli 3 it'll be already like this.

Comment: @Phiter you mean these new routes from API? I don't quite understand how they will be added to the existed routes.

Comment: No. I mean having your routes defined in the main file.

Comment: @Phiter oh I see. I do define them in a separate file `index.js` in the `routes` folder. :) I will try to add new routes in `main.js` file though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use addRoutes in this way:

```
import router from '@/router'
import Project from './pages/Project'
import Projects from './pages/Projects'

router.addRoutes([{
  path: '/projects',
  name: 'projects.projects',
  component: Projects,
  props: false
}, {
  path: '/projects/:id',
  name: 'projects.project',
  component: Project,
  props: true
}])
```

From docs:

> Dynamically add more routes to the router. The argument must be an Array using the same route config format with the routes constructor option

**Full example:**

You have the main router like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Home from '../components/pages/Home';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
 mode: 'history',
 routes: [
  {
   path: '/home',
   name: 'home',
   component: Home,
  },
  ],
});

export default router;
```

Now, you create a new page with the following structure.

```
-- NewPage
   -- NewPage.vue
   -- route.js
```

The `route.js` should look like this:

```
import router from '@/router' //importing the main router
import NewPage from './NewPage.vue'

router.addRoutes([
  {
    path: '/new-page',
    name: 'newPage',
    component: NewPage,
  },
])
```

Hope I helped you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, it didn't work out for me. When I try to address a new url like `localhost:8080/new-page', I receive 404 error because such page doesn't exist. :(